# How to add dataset to div using Pug?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to make blocks with dataset attributes using Pug.
The problem is that when I include them on a page they have text `NaN` inside them (picture below). How can I fix it?

Here is my mixin

```
mixin products(src, head, price)
  .favorites__block&attributes(attributes)= data-filter
    .favorites__image
      img(src=src, alt="").favorites__img
    .favorites__text
      span.favorites__title #{head}
      span.favorites__price $#{price}
      .favorites__btns
        button.favorites__cart Add to cart
        button.favorites__order Order
```

And the way I include it.

```
+products('assets/img/favorite_four.jpg', 'Machiato Coffee', '5')(data-filter='breakfast')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `(data-filter='breakfast')` you append to the call. As it stands, this mixin call now has two parameter lists, which is not allowd. You can, however, easily fix this by turning that `data-filter` element into a parameter of the mixin.

When I do that in your code example, it does work as expected (see [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/dRdmMd) for illustration).